# C++ How to remove items from std::map by value?

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdarray

My map:

```
std::map<std::array<byte, 16>, int> possible; // key is a byte array, value is a frequency of occurrence
```

I already filled the map. Now I need to remove the arrays that occurred once. It is necessary to remove from the map such pairs, the value of which is equal to one. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if):

```
const auto count = std::erase_if(possible, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    return value == 1;
});
```

Comment: Prior to C++20, you will have to use [`map::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) in a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` isn't designed to find elements by value, only by key. So, to do what you are asking for, you will have to manually loop through the `map` calling [`map::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) on the desired items, eg:

```
auto iter = possible.begin();
while (iter != possible.end()) {
  if (iter->second == 1) {
    iter = possible.erase(iter);
  } else {
    ++iter;
  }
}
```

In C++20 and later, you can use the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) overload of `std::erase_if()` instead, eg:

```
std::erase_if(possible, [](const auto& item) {
    return item.second == 1;
});
```